# Compute value of variable for multiple input values

Tags: tensorflow

I have a tensorflow graph which is trained. After training, I want to sample one variable for multiple intermediate values. Simplified:

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1])
b = a + 10
c = b * 10
```

Now I want to query `c` for values of `b`. Currently, I am using an outer loop

```
b_values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
samples = []
for b_value in b_values:
    samples += [sess.run(c,
                            feed_dict={b: [b_value]})]
```

This loop takes quite a bit of time, I think it is because `b_values` contains 5000 values in my case. Is there a way of running `sess.run` only once, and passing all `b_values` at once? I cannot really modify the graph `a->b->c`, but I could add something to it if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import time

a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])
b = a + 10
c = b * 10

sess = tf.Session()
b_values = np.random.randint(500,size=(5000,1))
samples = []
t =  time.time()
for b_value in b_values:
        samples += [sess.run(c,feed_dict={b: [b_value]})]

print time.time()-t
#print samples    

t=time.time()
samples =  sess.run(c,feed_dict={b:b_values})
print time.time()-t
#print samples
```

Output: (time in seconds)

```
0.874449968338
0.000532150268555
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: so the trick is in making the placeholder contain a "batch" dimension.. ok. I will wait and see if there is a solution where I can keep the original placeholder, otherwise I will accept the solution.

Comment: sure, Thanks. Update your post with new solution if you find the other way.

Comment: @P.R., did you find any smarter way to do this ?